# hexo+github， an error in the loading of the web page

Tags: github, github-pages, hexo

Local access to static web pages displays normal， but there are many errors when loading "https://360fengdai.github.io/devliu.github.io/", ask the old driver to help.

https://github.com/360fengdai/devliu.github.io.git

[git@github.com:360fengdai/devliu.github.io.git](http://git@github.com:360fengdai/devliu.github.io.git)

https://360fengdai.github.io/devliu.github.io/

[image: local load normal]

[image: Lose a lot of files]

[image: load error]

[image: config]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem because the name of the warehouse was wrong. It must be the user's name. I don't know why this place can be displayed normally, but it is already well.

My user name is 360fengdai,
So change the warehouse name to git@github.com:360fengdai/360fengdai.github.io.git

I referenced this address：https://pages.github.com/

Screenshot：[image]